# How to set the ng-options default using object?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

If i set a value dropdown value as a object is not working as expected.

for Example :
HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="lst as lst.name for lst in list"></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.list=[{'name':'Person-1','age':23},
  {'name':'Person-2','age':14},
  {'name':'Person-3','age':32},
  {'name':'Person-4','age':34},
  {'name':'Person-5','age':67},
  {'name':'Person-6','age':12}];

   $scope.selected = {'name':'Person-3','age':32};
```

If i assign a value as $scope.selected = $scope.list[0] is working fine. But now how can i assign a object to select.

i have attached the plunker link : http://plnkr.co/edit/WJo0W688s5NDN7kZYOPR?p=preview

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to set an object as selected it really needs to be an object of your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the object which you are assigning is not there in $scope.list. However it looks same but it's a different object. `$scope.list[0]` is working because it points to the same object reference which $scope.list is having.

See updated plunker so that you can understand.

[Updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bpGMfHQZlQtFQzZ9K3O?p=preview)

If you have objects then you need to iterate over the `$scope.list` by comparing properties and find index of appropriate object and use that index to assign selected object like.

```
$scope.selected = $scope.list[matchIndex]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jay but is there any other way than is iterating over the list

Comment: You can use Underscore.js library. There is function i.e pluck that can be used here.

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.selected = $scope.list[0];
```

This is how you set the default option